# 2 network cards on new database server

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, nic

I'm setting up a new database server (Windows 2008 R2) and the server has two GB network card (The server has actually 3 but I will keep one for backup), and I would like to know what is the best setting.

The server is connected to a HP ProCurve Switch 2824.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: question is asking for an opinion. dowvoted.

Comment: How should I best setup the 2 cards?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Speed... since the database will be used by a very busy website..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the hardware (which make and model is this server?), you can be able to create a "team" setup between these two network cards, so that they give you 2 GB/s throughput and high availability. This is a standard feature f.e. for HP NICs.

Comment: It's a Dell PowerEdge R510

Comment: the cards are broadcom bcm5716c netxtreme ii

Comment: I download the software from the broadcom website and created a team. thanks